# Does $A$ have infinite order in $G= \langle A,B \ |\ B A B^{-1} = A^2 \rangle $?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, group-presentation, geometric-group-theory

I have a group (arising from the fundamental group of a manifold)
$$G= \langle A,B \ |\ B A B^{-1} = A^2\rangle $$
and

> I would like to show that $A$ is an element of infinite order inside $G$.

Notice that in the abelianization ${\rm Ab}(G)\simeq \mathbb{Z}$, the image of $A$ is the identity.
Nevertheless, $A$ is a non-trivial element in $G$, indeed we can find a representation $G\to{\rm SL}(2;\mathbb C)$ that sends $A$ to the diagonal matrix  ${\rm diag}(e^{i2\pi/3},e^{-i 2 \pi/3})$.

Comment: This is a [Baumslag-Solitar group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baumslag%E2%80%93Solitar_group).

Comment: More generally, this is an example of an [HNN-extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HNN_extension), with base group $\langle A\mid -\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}$. In HNN-extensions, base groups always embed, QED.

Comment: [This is answered on Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/126375/20787) by.... umm.... @DietrichBurde! Which uses a faithful linear representation, by the way.

Comment: I did not know any of the facts in the above comments, now I know more than one way to prove it, thank you all!

Comment: See also the answer by user1729 is (in the duplicate): Fact 1. *Every non-trivial element of BS(m,n) has infinite order.*

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm not convinced by that duplicate link, as my justification there is simply the hint I gave here! So I've opened it and re-closed it as a duplicate of a question where you have given the linear representation, as I felt that is more meaningful. (Or maybe this is an opportunity for someone to write out a proof here that either (1) the representation is faithful, or (2) base groups of HNN-extensions embed?)

Comment: @user1729 Yes, you are right. I think this is better. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I re-opened the question because although it is answered in the linked post of @DietrichBurde, that post is over on mathoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments have already given two solutions; here's a third.  (It's not really new, just a disguised version of those arguments, but I like the elementary description it gives.)

Choose $n$ odd and consider the cyclic group $C_n=\langle\rho\rangle$.  The map $\phi:C_n\to C_n$; $$\phi(g)=g^2$$ generates a subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}{(C_n)}$ that is cyclic of order $m$.  Now form a semidirect product $$C_n\rtimes C_m$$ where conjugation by the generator of $C_m$ acts as $\phi$.  Then $$\tau\rho\tau^{-1}=\phi(\rho)=\rho^2$$ and so the map $\psi:G\to C_n\rtimes C_m$; \begin{gather*}
\psi(A)=\rho \\
\psi(B)=\tau
\end{gather*} is a homomorphism.

Moreover, $\psi(A)$ has order $n$.  Varying $n$, we see that $G$ has quotients in which the image of $A$ has arbitrarily-large order.  But quotients can only decrease the order of an element, so $A$ must have infinite order to begin with.

Comment: I like this description too! (+1)